# Are these temperatures on non-retina Macbook Pro 13 Mid-2012 normal when browsing?

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I wonder if the temperatures on my non-retina Macbook Pro 13 Mid-2012 normal. I browse using Firefox. I tried using Safari but no noticable difference. CPU load is low. OS X version 10.8.5.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes - everything looks normal. Battery and charger are good. HDD and GPU are fine. CPU and cores running cool.

T-JUNCTION of the processor is 105 °C for the i5 (*[Intel® Core™ i5-3210M Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/65708/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-BGA)*) and the i7 (*[Intel® Core™ i7-3520M Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/64893/Intel-Core-i7-3520M-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz)* ). The *Junction Temperature* is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die.

The temperature shown in your screenshot is ~30 degrees Celsius lower than the max. allowed. So I would expect it to be still completely normal.

---

Surfing with a Intel® Core™ i7-2720QM Processor (T-JUNCTION 100 °C) in a MacBook Pro with a CPU-load of 15% and an environmental temperature of ~10 °C I get an average of about 60 °C.